# Distributive Law Simplification

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to write a procedure that makes use of the distributive property of an algebraic expression to simplify it:

```
(dist '(+ x y (exp x) (* x 5) y (* y 6)))
=> (+ (* x (+ 1 5))
      (* y (+ 1 1 6))
      (exp x))

(dist '(+ (* x y) x y))
=> (+ (* x (+ y 1))
      y)
; or
=> (+ (* y (+ x 1))
      x)
```

As the second example shows, there can be more than one possible outcome, I don't need to enumerate them all, just a valid one. I'm wondering if someone could provide me with at least a qualitative description of how they would start attacking this problem? Thanks :)

Comment: I haven't taken the time to parse through the first example, but your second example is "factoring out" the common x or y.  Are you looking to do that, or "distribute through"?  I know both follow from the distributive law, but I suppose the answers might be different, depending on what you're looking for.

Comment: Precisely, I'm looking to simply an expression by "factoring out" any common factors. That perhaps would have been a more better way of explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

Oleg Kiselyov's [pmatch macro](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-pub/c311/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=pmatch.scm) makes distributing a factor across terms pretty easy:

```
(define dist
  (λ (expr)
    (pmatch expr
      [(* ,factor (+ . ,addends))
        `(+ ,@(map (λ (addend)
                     (list factor addend))
                   addends))]
      [else
        expr])))

(dist '(* 5 (+ x y))) => (+ (5 x) (5 y))
```

The main trick is to match a pattern and extract elements from the expression from the corresponding slots in the pattern. This requires a `cond` and `let` with tricky expressions to `cdr` to the right place in the list and `car` out the right element. `pmatch` writes that `cond` and `let` for you.

Factoring out common terms is harder because you have to look at all the subexpressions to find the common factors and then pull them out:

```
(define factor-out-common-factors
  (λ (expr)
    (pmatch expr
      [(+ . ,terms) (guard (for-all (λ (t) (eq? '* (car t)))
                                    terms))
        (let ([commons (common-factors terms)])
          `(* ,@commons (+ ,@(remove-all commons (map cdr terms)))))]
      [else
        expr])))

(define common-factors
  (λ (exprs)
    (let ([exprs (map cdr exprs)]) ; remove * at start of each expr
      (fold-right (λ (factor acc)
                    (if (for-all (λ (e) (member factor e))
                                 exprs)
                        (cons factor acc)
                        acc))
                  '()
                  (uniq (apply append exprs))))))

(define uniq
  (λ (ls)
    (fold-right (λ (x acc)
                  (if (member x acc)
                      acc
                      (cons x acc)))
                '()
                ls)))


(factor-out-common-factors '(+ (* 2 x) (* 2 y)))
=> (* 2 (+ (x) (y)))
```

The output could be cleaned up some more, this doesn't cover factoring out a 1, and  `remove-all` is missing, but I'll leave all that to you.

Answer (score 0):

A very general approach:

```
(dist expr var-list)
=> expr factored using terms in var-list
```

`dist` would have to know about "distributable" functions like `+,-,*,/,etc` and how each of them behave.  If, say, it only knew about the first four, then :

```
(dist expr var-list
  (if (empty? var-list) expr
    (let* ([new-expr (factor expr (first var-list))])
      (return "(* var " (dist new-expr (rest var-list)))))
```

That "return "(* var " " is not correct syntax, but you probably already knew that.  I'm not a racket or lisp expert by any means, but basically this comes down to string processing?  In any case, `factor` needs to be fleshed out so that it removes a single `var` from `*` functions and all of the `var` from `+` functions (replacing them with 1).  It also needs to be smart enough to only do it when there are at least two replacements (otherwise we haven't actually done anything).

Comment: If you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do, you should be using a macro (or possibly `apply`) rather than string processing.